# How to track which tables/views/etc depends from a table, in Oracle

Tags: oracle, dependencies

How to know which objects (tables/views/etc) uses a certain table?

I have to replace my table PRICE.
So, is there something like?

```
select system.dependencies from PRICE
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT NAME
from user_dependencies
where referenced_name = 'PRICE'
```