# how to recover all calls to an Oracle view

Tags: oracle, view, dependencies

I have a view in an Oracle DB. I would like to retrieve all views, functions, procedure and other objects) dependent of this view and calling this view.

Could you help me please to do that because I don't know how to do that in Oracle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track which tables/views/etc depends from a table, in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737696/how-to-track-which-tables-views-etc-depends-from-a-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from dba_dependencies 
where name = 'TheNameOfYourView' 
or referenced_name = 'TheNameOfYourView';
```

That will show you everything it depends on as well as everything that is dependent on it.